# Non-Zero Metrics-FileBeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I am using elasic.co/filebeat:6.3.1 and ELK elastic.co:6.3.0 in ubuntu as docker, while running filebeat facing this issue,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rZjt.png

And my filebeat.yml is

```
filebeat.inputs:

    # Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
    # you can use different inputs for various configurations.
    # Below are the input specific configurations.

  - type: log

   # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: false

   # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
 paths:
     - /usr/local/java/ABC_LOGS/*/*.log
     #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*
     #============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

       filebeat.config.modules:
         # Glob pattern for configuration loading
        path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

             # Set to true to enable config reloading
       reload.enabled: false

          #==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

       setup.template.settings:
       index.number_of_shards: 3
       #index.codec: best_compression
       #_source.enabled: false

              #============================== Dashboards =====================================
          setup.dashboards.enabled: true

      #============================== Kibana =====================================

         setup.kibana:
            host: "10.0.0.0:5601"

       #-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
          output.elasticsearch:
            hosts: ["10.0.0.0:9200"]
```

Please help me,Thanks in advance

Comment: What issue are you referring to? I see only INFO logs in there?

Comment: Hi @Val, Thanks for your reply Actually in my filebeat.yml i gave some path /usr/local/java/ABC/*/*.log  but logs are not coming in kibana Dashboard.

Comment: And Elasticseach created index for filebeat but logs are not coming and filebeat didn't show any error,And i run metricbeat it works properly ,Please help me

Comment: You might want to set `logging.level: debug` in `filebeat.yml` in order to see if you can get more information

Comment: @Val please see the image       https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGSz6.png

Comment: In Kibana Dashboard i am getting error like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuYIU.png

Comment: are you sure that there are documents in the last 15 minutes (see your time picker)?

Comment: i change the time picker but no logs are there in kibana .@Val i am new to filebeat,in filebeat.yml i gave 1 path(see above conf file) and i enabled system and mysql modules in the system.yml i change the syslog path ,my problem is i am not getting any logs into my kibana dashboard in elasticsearch index is created properly.

Comment: Hi, How did you resolve this issue? @ThrivarnaG